# Xcode does not see my apple tv

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm starting a project and I plug my apple tv 4 in to my mac. I just updated all software [xcode 7.2.1] and mac is latest El Capitan. Apple tv latest version.  Where my device normally pops up I show no devices. I know my connecter works because if I proceed to Windows-devices it shows up under it's alias of "Living room". I plug in my iPad and several other devices and they show up in no time. I tried plugging it in while it was connected to a monitor to see if there was a "trust box" to be checked. Nothing. I've rebooted, and restarted Xcode and I'm out of ideas. Is there a manual way to enter the info so it will get the proper provisioning profile?

Comment: When the Apple TV is connected to your computer, and you open iTunes, does it see it? It should have options to Eject or Restore the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Wireless debugging is quite glitchy. I turned off Wi-Fi on my Macbook, then turned it on and that worked: my Apple TV got appeared in Devices.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the machine running Xcode and the AppleTV aren't connected to **exactly** the same WiFi network - this includes if the type differs such as having a WiFi network that operates on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz (with the same SSID network name) then the two devices need to be connected on the same frequency range - if necessary you may need to rename/switch off one type temporarily. It can also make a difference if you have them connected to different Access Points that use the same SSID.

Once they're paired it doesn't seem to matter which WiFi network they're on as long as it's on the same LAN/IP range.

Answer (score -1):

My bad. I made a rookie mistake and didn't see that I needed to check the tvos box when I started the project. As soon as I did everything was fine.

Comment: This worked for me. In the templates to start the project I selected a tvOS single page view application instead of an iOS single page view application and that made my device appear. Thanks for the tip!